# How to benchmark others' apps without expensive purchases

Tags: mobile-application, research, push-notification

In order to improve our airline travel booking app's notification experience, I'm conducting a benchmarking study where I hope to look at the various notifications at different points of the user journey (e.g. online check-in open, miles have been added, change of flight time).

However, in order to see these notifications in other airline travel booking apps, I would need to actually purchase tickets from these airlines.

Is there any other way I might be able to get to see these notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working with each airline's developer experience team by searching for `[airline] developer experience`. You can often find a support contact or relationship manager through each of the airlines' developer portals.

Once you've established contact, ask if there is documentation on each notification use case; identifying notifications along the happy path might not uncover everything the airline provides. (There might be different notifications sent to VIPs, for example.)